# Should I "deal" with my blisters?

Tags: running

Fellow runners,

I am starting to enter the business end of my marathon training.
My long runs are around 20-22 miles and they are starting to take their toll on my feet.

I have a particularly angry looking blister on my little toe that is causing me quite a lot of distress - annoying really as this is the first serious blister I've had since I started my training.

I'm concerned that this may interrupt my training schedule (it really does look quite evil).

Is this something I should deal with or let it go down naturally?
If I should deal with it - what is the best way?

Thanks!

Comment: An amazing achievement .. re blisters perhaps the info here may be relevant? http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2983/what-are-the-best-methods-to-prevent-and-treat-foot-blisters/2985#2985

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put something on the blister while running. Options include Dr. Scholl's moleskin, molefoam, or some other type of blister-specific band-aid. The gel cushion ones should work.

It's best to let it go down naturally, but don't let the blister pop. If it gets bigger, drain it by dipping a needle in peroxide or rubbing alcohol, then puncturing the base and pressing the blister to drain it.

To prevent blisters, try different shoes or socks. I had blisters between my toes until I got toe socks. I love my Injinji socks. If that doesn't work, try putting moleskin on the parts of your feet where blisters tend to occur. Put moleskin on red, sore spots (hot spots) that are precursors to blisters.